# D3 Circle-Packing throws NaN and Infinity error or crashes browser

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the example of the [D3 circle packing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ca5b03a33affa4160321) with my own data, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3k947z2/3/

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "asdfgh",
    "category": "C",
    "color": "#F29999",
    "count": 0
}, {
    "name": "asdfgh",
    "category": "C",
    "color": "#D883A7",
    "count": 29
}, {
    "name": "asdfgh",
    "category": "C",
    "color": "#F05067",
    "count": 0
}, {
    "name": "asdfgh",
    "category": "C",
    "color": "#E86F6F",
    "count": 0
}, {
    "name": "asdfgh",
    "category": "C",
    "color": "#CE8C8C",
    "count": 13
}];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

var format = d3.format(",d");

var pack = d3.pack()
  .size([width - 2, height - 2])
  .padding(3);

(function() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  var root = d3.hierarchy({
      children: [{
        children: data
      }]
    })
    .sort(function(a,b){ return b.data.count - a.data.count; })
    .sum(function(d) {
      return d.count;
    });

  pack(root);

  var node = svg.select("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "node" + (!d.children ? " node--leaf" : d.depth ? "" : " node--root");
    })
    .each(function(d) {
      d.node = this;
    });

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return "node-" + d.id;
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.r;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.data.color;
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="360" height="360">
  <g transform="translate(1,1)"></g>
</svg>
```

I don't know what is going on exactly in the d3.hierarchy(), but changing some numbers in the data can make my browser crash. For example you could try to change the count for the blue circle to 50 (from 55). Or 1, or 0... and the browser does not respond, nor does it log any errors. These are just random combinations I tried.

Can anyone explain what is going on? Any idea how to investigate what causes the problems?

Comment: Apparently, adding a descending sort for the count values solved the problem:

   `.sort(function(a,b){
      return b.data.count - a.data.count;
    })`

I guess, it is because d3-hierachy places the first 3 circles - and if those are 0 it becomes difficult to place the rest...

Comment: please post that as an answer, so that it's helpful for others.

Comment: I still have NaN and Infinity occurrences: https://jsfiddle.net/c3k947z2/3/